# What is the equivalent PowerShell command for 'Network Reset' UI option on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

There's an option on the network settings called "Network Reset" that allows the admin of the device to "Reset" all network configs, is there an equivalent for this but done via CLI on PowerShell?

[image: See this image]

Comment: That tool does a lot of items. You have to write a script that does all the same steps. There is no single command in PS for this. That like is also not a single thing. It's calling about 9+ underlying resources in kind. You can easily replicate that as long as you know all the service names you need to tap. Also, that PS script would need to be executed as an admin, since these are system-wide changes.

Comment: **Why** would you need to completely reset the network frequently? Is there a recurring issue with the network? If so, describe the issue and you might find an answer here.

Comment: We run a VPN service called WARP that from time to time just croaks, L2 doesn't fix it, I have to login and use the UI which is annoying, that's why I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: @postanote I see, thanks. Well I guess there's not much that I can do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```ps
$computerName = "COMPUTER_NAME"
$scriptBlock = {
    netsh int ip reset
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Looks right. Don't have time to test (for real this time). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`Netsh int ip reset`

That will reset your tcpip stack. Should be easy enough to build a PS wrapper for it. I don't have the time. But maybe gpt does.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).